# Would Entity Framework be an overkill for a small-business app?

Tags: c#, orm

I am creating a C#/SqlServer app in a small business for specific industry.  It is a rewrite of a VB6 app which had almost 100 database tables.  It does not sit in a larger enterprise structure of applications and databases like some applications might.  It is standalone and will only ever have about a 1-3 developers working on it.

Would Entity Framework be an overkill for such an application?  I am looking for at least a micro-ORM to simplify the data-access parts of the app, but is a full blown ORM an overkill?

EDIT: I would have thought ORMs largely suit larger development environments.

Comment: Overkill? Is the client paying per byte of referenced assemblies?

Comment: @Jon: I was under the impression EF was quite a heavy layer.

Comment: OP probably means the perceived overhead of either generating a model, or using code first w/ POCOs, configuring EF, etc. In reality the overhead is small compared to the CRUD you'd have to write for even the smallest applications.

Comment: Are you just looking for simple CRUD functionality in your data access? Or is it going to involve some pretty complex queries?

Comment: @CraigJ: Please put in words what you might expect to gain by using a "light" layer.

Comment: @Jon: perhaps halve the lines of code when accessing the DB. I've found the raw ADO.NET patterns to be quite irritating.

Comment: @CraigJ: Take a look at some EF usage examples then, which should answer your question (hint: use EF).

Comment: If it's just a small app and you don't need all the extra functionality entity framework gives you then you could just use LINQ to SQL.

Comment: @ThePower: not really anything complex.

Answer (score 3):

Whether EF is "overkill" depends entirely on the context; indeed, you mention "quite a heavy later", but in many ways that is *irrelevant* for a "small-business app", since you won't ever be subjecting it to massive load. You could even argue, then, that *doing anything but* using an ORM is overkill (in that it adds development effort).

You also mention micro-ORMs; indeed they will reduce a lot of raw ADO.NET code (which you single out in the comments). Simple.Data provides a nice layer of abstraction, aboiding the need to write the TSQL too - probably not a bad starting point, but with 100 tables, I can see a lot of attractive aspects of EF/L2S/etc (in particular for stubbing out all your objects). However, EF does **itself** have plenty of... "features" (meaning: places to stub your toes), which mean you will still have to learn some of how EF wants to work. [Invariably, all abstractions do this to some extent](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html) - so it a case of weighing up this cost vs the cost of doing more manually.

Answer (score 2):

It is **definitely** not overkill.

In my workplace we either use EF4.1 or our own ORM. It does speed up development, avoiding you to write glue code to map rows to instances.

We use SQL only when

- performance trumps code readability/maintanability
- we have queries that ORM just can't handle

Comment: That doesn't sound very good for EF.  Performance problems and queries that it can't handle!

Answer (score 0):

An ORM is overkill only if you feel it this way. With a hundred tables, it looks justified.

You might prefer some micro ORM (like [SimpleData](https://github.com/markrendle/Simple.Data) or [Massive](https://github.com/robconery/massive)), but it's up to you : a micro-orm might involve a too lose coopling with your DB when EF forces the strong typing.